# Movie: boy escapes the real world and goes to a fantasy world with big furry trolls

Tags: story-identification, movie

It's about a boy who escapes the real world and goes to this fantasy world where he befriends these big furry trolls, the trolls are animated, but the boy is played by an actor.

Comment: Please visit https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info. It's got some more questions that might help you figure out more information. And, just to clarify, the trolls were animated, but the boy was live-action? Or was the entire world live-action?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: @isak is ask Do you have any more information like year/decade the film is from, country if origin etc?

Comment: You received two answers; if you want (but there's no obligation), you can accept one by clicking the checkmark on the left, providing it's the right movie. If you don't want to accept an answer that's totally fine, but please tell us via a comment if it was the right movie or if the search continues :)

Comment: I doubt it's  [H. R. Pufnstuf](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.R._Pufnstuf) but you really haven't given us enough information for anyone to prove otherwise.

Answer (score 25):

*Where the Wild Things Are* (2009)?

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0386117/):

> A young boy named Max has an active imagination, and he will throw fits if others don't go along with what he wants. Max - following an incident with Claire (his sister) and her friends, and following a tantrum which he throws as a result of his Mother paying more attention to her boyfriend than to him - runs away from home. Wearing his wolf costume at the time, **Max not only runs away physically, but runs toward a world in his imagination. This world, an ocean away, is inhabited by large wild beasts**, including one named Carol who is much like Max himself in temperament. Instead of eating Max like they normally would with creatures of his type, **the wild things befriend Max after he proclaims himself a king who can magically solve all their problems**.

---

Found by memory. Never seen it but I remembered the big furry things as well (and the funny pun in the translated title in my mother tongue, French).

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on said pun? My curiosity is now piqued.

Comment: @TheNate it's called _Max et les Maximonstres_ in French, so something like _Max and the Maximonsters_ in English, it being "punny" because that means the monsters are "maxi monsters", presumably some tough beasts, and their name beginning with "Max" (the protagonist's name, also in the title) implies they're Max's monsters. It's not really _funny_, but it's the kind of quip that would stuck in my brain ten years ago ;p

Comment: Suppose its only fair to say its based on the book of the same name.

Answer (score 9):

This seems like [*Where the Wild Things Are*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_the_Wild_Things_Are_(film)) (2009):

[image: film poster, boy looking up at furry monster]

In the movie, a boy named Max runs away, traversing a pond that becomes an ocean to find an island with Wild Things, which do look like trolls.

Comment: Not sure what the point of resurrecting this question was with an answer that says the same thing as the existing one.